# How Does the Body Know a Finger is Fully developed?

Tags: development

When a baby is being developed inside the womb,

1) how does the baby's body know a finger, or any other part of the body, has been fully developed?

2) following question, how does it "stop" the development of that part? What kind of signals are being communicated here?

3) I have hairy arms. The length of the hair is almost the same length if i don't cut it. If it breaks, it grows back almost the same length. How does the body know the current length and how to stop when it reaches the "target length"? Is it the same "procedure" as the development of parts inside the womb?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The two first questions are related, the third question is quite different. Please always narrow down your post to a single question. Also, the first two questions are in themselves already quite broad. You might want to read a  bit more about [developmental biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developmental_biology)

Comment: For the third question, you might want to read related posts; [Why does hair grow after trimming but remains at a constant length after a while?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27528/why-does-hair-grow-after-trimming-but-remains-at-a-constant-length-after-a-while) and [Why can hair grow without limit while eyebrow cannot?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1267/why-can-hair-grow-without-limit-while-eyebrow-cannot)

Comment: I am interested in the "communication part". I chose hair as an example because it regrows. I could have chosen anything that regenerates to the original shape in the body.

Comment: Is there a common "algorithm" the body follow for development and regeneration or is there different once for every scenario?

Comment: Yes but the case of hair is very different that the case of finger development.

Comment: Fair enough. The hair is a bad example,

Comment: Yes, there is some kind of "algorithm". Describing this "algorithm" would require writing a whole book. And in fact many people have been writing books on the development of organisms. This is why the question is too broad in my opinion. Your question sounds to me like the question "Can you explain to me how biology works?" might sound to you.

Comment: So Developmental Biology is the door for my question, yes?

Comment: Yes, it is! If you are interested in following a class, you can for example consider this [MIT intro class](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biology/7-22-developmental-biology-fall-2005/). More introductory and less complete, there is also [this Khan academy series of videos](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/developmental-biology). Note: I have not attended any of these two classes, I just googled them so I can't comment on their quality but MIT classes tend to be pretty good. You could open a new post to ask for good ressources in developmental biology if you want to. Good luck!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Bio.SE! Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the site and earn yourself your first badge. Have a nice stay!